# Access resouce file(xml) in springboot java application

Tags: xml, spring-boot

I am creating a springboot java application. I need help in accessing a resource file(a xml file) and parse it. I am using gradle to build the project. Do i have to add any dependency in gradle while compiling? How will I be able to access the resource file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resource files are located in classpath. You could follow a standard way to read this file, like the one below:

```
InputStream yourStream = null;
try {
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("/folder/file.xml");
yourStream = cpr.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
       log.error("This is the exception: " + e);
    } finally {
        cleanUpResource(yourStream); //close stream etc
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using @Value

You can inject a Resource with @Value:

```
@Value("classpath:data/file.xml")
Resource resourceFile;
```

- Using ResourceLoader
  Autowire resourceLoader and then retrieve  resource with getResource

  [image]